# Переопределение метода get_queryset в Django Admin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему может не работать такая конструкция:

```
class FastCountQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def count(self):
        pass


@admin.register(ItemOOSLog)
class ItemOOSLogAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ItemOOSLogAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs._chain(__class__=FastCountQuerySet)
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы при использовании метода get_queryset, использовался мой класс FastCountQuerySet вместо QuerySet.
Нашёл, что это можно реализовать через `qs._chain(__class__=FastCountQuerySet)`, но это не работает, используется обычный QuerySet.

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось следующим:

```
class FastCountQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def count(self):
        pass


@admin.register(ItemOOSLog)
class ItemOOSLogAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(ItemOOSLogAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs.__class__ = FastCountQuerySet
        return qs._chain()
```